# Error while adding WCF reference in the Windows Form Application Solution

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://192.168.1.86:8080/spectrum/restful/models'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="spectrum"'.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

[image: This is the AUnthencation PopUp]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjjD.png)
[image: Error That is comming while adding the reference in the windows solution]

Any help please !!

Comment: The service is available only for authenticated users. Thus, you have to supply credentials to get the metadata, otherwise, you can't connect to this service in any way.

Comment: Yes Jacob, I have supplied the credentials but still I am not able to connect. But if I consume the service using soap-UI by passing the Credentials in that case I am getting the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string res = string.Empty;

```
        string url = "http://192.168.1.86:8080/spectrum/restful/models";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + password;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            HttpStatusCode errorCode = response.StatusCode;
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            res = responseFromServer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (response == null && ex.Message.Contains("400"))
                res = "NoSuchUser";
            else
                res = ex.Message;
        }
```